# What can I delete in registry Editor - need to remove PCUPGRADENOW

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I want to delete the non essential registries in : Software - Microsoft - Windows - Current Version - Run.

The reason is I get a pop up from PCUPGRADENOW (I think a virus)and I have followed all the steps in the following blog : http://blog.vilmatech.com/remove-pcupgradenow-com-pop-malware-latest-removal/

I am stuck at the part where the say in the registry delete the .exe

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run “.exe”
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\run\`

MY REGISTRY:

```
Name                          Type           Data
(Default)                     REG_SZ         (value not set)
EPLTarget\P0000000000000000   REG_SZ         C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\E_YATII6E.EXE /EPT "EPLTarget\P0000000000000000" /M "L550 Series"
Sidebar                       REG_SZ         C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe /autoRun
swg                           REG_SZ        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\GoogleToolbarNotifier\GoogleToolbarNotifier.exe"
```

Comment: The instructions on that blog for what  to remove from the registry look like nonsense. You have the right idea in looking within those keys it mentions. I'd find better instructions if I were you. And try some anti-malware program.

Comment: try the advice on this site it mentions some programs to run that I know are ok.. like hitman and malware bytes http://malwaretips.com/blogs/pcupgradenow-com-virus/

Answer (score 0):

These registry keys contain programs that startup when windows starts. If there is an error here, you'll get a popup saying windows could not find a program to execute.

When you navigate to this key, and on the left side, you right click the key and choose Export... you can save the content of this key as a backup to a .reg file. Once you have made the backup, you can delete anything you want and test if the problem is gone. If you deleted an entry and you want it back, just doubleclick the .reg file you made, and everything is undone.

Be careful though, editing the registry can cause windows to stop working correctly or even boot. There will not be much trouble if you are in the following 4 keys:

```
HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_LocalMachine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LocalMachine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Note that the LocalMachine part requires administrative privileges whereas the CurrentUser does not. If you have spyware and it was caused on your account, and the other accounts on your pc don't have it, it will not be in LocalMachine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for programs that start up with your computer, give [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) a try. It will give you more information about your startup programs than what you're looking at wil.

> This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and shows you the entries in the order Windows processes them. These programs include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys. You can configure Autoruns to show other locations, including Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more.